# ShowDialog returns immediately after a handled exception in .net compact framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

The problem I am having is that for some reason ShowDialog returns immediately after handle an exception. However, it works for MessageBox.Show() or at the second time I call ShowDialog. What is the best workaround for this problem?

I was only able to find [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94356/modal-windows-in-net-compact-framework-application-stop-working-if-unhandled-exception-on-modal-dialog-is-raised#). And I cannot believe that no one else has this issue.

I am using .net compact framework 3.5. Sample code:

```
try
{
  using(SomeForm f = new SomeForm())
  {
    f.ShowDialog();
  }
}
catch(SomeException)
{
  using(SomeOtherForm f = new SomeOtherForm())
  {
    f.ShowDialog(); // this returns immediately
                    // if this is MessageBox.Show(), it works correctly.
    f.ShowDialog(); // then this works fine
  }
}
```

Comment: Write a FormClosing event handler in SomeOtherForm, set a breakpoint on it and post the stack trace you see when it breaks.

Comment: Unfortunately closing event is not called.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered the following in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619863/problem-using-unhandledexception-in-windows-mobile-app/2665943#2665943), which I think is related to the same problem. Although in your case 2) might not work (unless manually blocking the thread).

> I came across this problem as well.
>   This is a known issue in .NET CF
>   (v2.0), but I also had it while using
>   v3.5 (although the situations in which
>   it occurs are more specific). You can
>   find the (old and still active) bug
>   report here.
>
> Calling MessageBox.Show() causes it to
>   close immediately, but in my case
>   there were two workarounds:
>
> 1) Call
>   the MessageBox.Show() a second time.
>   It then does block until closed by the
>   user. You can check the first
>   MessageBox.Show() closed prematurely
>   by checking the DialogResult. I don't
>   remember which result it returned
>   exactly when it failed, I remember it
>   giving a non-default result.
>
> 2) Create a custom Form and call
>   ShowDialog() on that. It worked for
>   me, but others have reported it
>   doesn't work. You could also call
>   Show() and make it blocking yourself
>   (don't forget to call
>   Application.DoEvents() so it keeps
>   processing events).

Comment: Last week, I found this answer which solves the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724644/windowsmobile-application-exits-after-handling-exception-from-dialogform