# Windows Mobile exception handling between forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile

My windows mobile application is being closed after catching exception from other Form. I narrowed problem to such example:

Form1:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (MyException exc)
        {
        }
    }
```

and in Form2:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new MyException();
    }
```

This code works fine under windows 8 but windows mobile 6.5 application is being closed.
Debugger shows that Application.Run(new Form1()); is just ended.
I am confused. Why is it happened ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724644/windowsmobile-application-exits-after-handling-exception-from-dialogform . Can you verify if it's about the same version?  My bad for not listing that.

Comment: Yes. I can confim. This is the same issue.