# Why is UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject an object and not an Exception?

Tags: .net, exception, unhandled-exception

Why is `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject` an object and not an `Exception`?

I am attaching to `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.

I would like to cast `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject` to an `Exception` and interogate it.

And with this in mind will it ever be null?

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unhandledexceptioneventargs.exceptionobject.aspx) is not exatly useful.

> Gets the unhandled exception object.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

This cannot be typed to Exception because it's possible to throw objects in .Net that do not derive from System.Exception.  This is not possible in C# or VB.Net but it is possible in other CLR based languages.  Hence the API must support this possibility and uses the type object.

So while it shouldn't ever be null, it may not in fact be a System.Exception.

See CLI spec section 10.5 (specifically CLS rule 40) for more details

Comment: Thanks Jared
I have added your answer and a link back here to the msdn community content

Comment: So casting it to Exception in C# will not be a problem? right?

Comment: @MubasharAhmad it can be a problem if the type isn't derived from `System.Exception`. The exception could've resulted from a non-CLI compliant language which decide to throw a `System.Int32`.  Newer versions of the CLR will auto-wrap this in `System.Exception` anyways but this is a setting that can be disabled

Comment: @MubasharAhmad I would recommend that you use the 'as' cast, so that in the case that the object is not derived from type Exception, the cast defaults to null, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Why then `try-catch` block doesnt allow to catch non-Exception objects?

Comment: @AgentFire because, as JaredPar said, C# does not *support* exceptions that don't derive from Exception. The .NET framework and .NET runtime do, but the C# language does not.

Answer (score 83):

In addition to what Jared has already mentioned, you can safely cast to `Exception` in .NET Framework 2.0 and higher if `RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute(WrapNonExceptionThrows=true)` has been applied to your assembly (will be added automatically by the C# and VB compilers).

When this attribute has been applied, non-Exception "exceptions" will be wrapped in `RuntimeWrappedException`.

Comment: Thank-you for the information; I was handling this manually, i.e., wrapped it in a RuntimeWrappedException if it failed to cast an exception.