# C# conversion error

Tags: c#

I get the following error from the code shown below and can not find a way to cast the object properly. Any help greatly appreciated.

The error occurs on the ex = e.ExceptionObject; line.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Exception'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266) -
>   C:\DocmentMDB\DocumentMDB.ConvertedToC#\ErrorHandler.cs:59,9

```
public static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // handles all unhandled (i.e. no Catch block) exceptions
    // the following code must be placed in Sub Main and the project
    // use Sub Main as startup
    //Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    //AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf myExceptionHandler

    Exception ex = null;
    ex = e.ExceptionObject;

    string strErrorMsg = null;
    string strDisplayMsg = null;
    string strPrintMsg = null;
    int intLoc = 0;

    strErrorMsg = "Unhandled Error In : " + strFormName + " - " + ex.TargetSite.Name + Constants.vbCrLf + Constants.vbCrLf + ex.Message;

    strPrintMsg = "Error detected: " + DateAndTime.Now + Constants.vbCrLf + Constants.vbCrLf + strErrorMsg + Constants.vbCrLf + Constants.vbCrLf + ex.StackTrace;

    strDisplayMsg = "Report this error to your System Administrator" + Constants.vbCrLf + Constants.vbCrLf + strErrorMsg + Constants.vbCrLf + Constants.vbCrLf + "Click YES to print this message.";

    if (MessageBox.Show(strDisplayMsg, "Unhandled Program Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
        // print the error message
        ErrPrint myPrintObject = new ErrPrint(strPrintMsg);
        myPrintObject.Print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
```

Comment: Thank you Uwe. Since I am a VB.Net programmer, I am not use to the tight typeing of C# but I am getting it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly cast it: `(Exception) e.ExceptionObject` There may be conditions in which you are expecting a certain kind of exception:

```
if (e.ExceptionObject is InvalidOperationException)
{
    // ...
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

For the reasons discussed in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913472), `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject` is statically typed as `object`, not `Exception`. So if you want to treat it as an `Exception`, you will have to cast.

Note that as per one of the answers there, it is usually the case that you can safely direct cast (ie, cast with `(Exception)`).