# How to Run a Windows Service at specific time each day

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I have a windows service that i need to run at specific time of day.Suppose the time id 11:00 PM.At present i have code to run this service on everyday but how to add time variant into this i am not able to get that.
Here is my code in c#..

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;//set interval of one day 
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        start_timer();

    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add your code here
        readDataFromAd();

    }
    private static void start_timer()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Please help me in defining the time also along with the interval.The time Should be 11:00 PM and the timer should execute the Method Everyday.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Service to run a function at specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151363/windows-service-to-run-a-function-at-specified-time)

Answer (score 5):

**I would recommend changing your approach.** Services are normally used for long running processes that are always running.  For processes that run on a schedule, windows has a built in component called **"Task Scheduler"** that is designed for running applications on a schedule.

You can simply take your application service code and paste it into a windows console application and then schedule the resultant exe to run on whatever schedule you see fit by using the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to use Quartz schedular in windows service. Using quartz you can also schedule multiple jobs in a single service based on time for execution like daily on 5 A.M. , every hour, every minute, weekly etc. It is too flexible to use.

Comment: Agreed, in addition there is windows scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is great, but if all you want to do is run your service once a day then the builtin Windows Task Scheduler is a good option too.

You would:

1. Change your service to remove the timer/sleep and call readDataFromAd() from a thread started from OnStart() ([discussion on why a thread may be necessary here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380060/need-to-increase-window-service-timeout))
2. Create a task in the Task Scheduler that executes the following command at 11 PM:

   NET START Your-Service-Name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

                _timer.Enabled = true;

                DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                int intervalToElapse = 0;
                DateTime scheduleTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TimeToRun"]);

                if (currentTime <= scheduleTime)
                    intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;
                else
                    intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.AddDays(1).Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;

                _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(intervalToElapse * 1000);
                _timer.AutoReset = true;
                _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
                _timer.Start();
        }

private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           //do your thing
//set it to run on a 24-hour basis
     _timer.Interval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;

}
```