# Is there a centralised error handling process in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to centralize the error handling or exceptions handling without using try catch methods?

Comment: Are you interested in centralized error fallback, so that you can log and display a friendly message before shutting down the application or are you talking about a central place to actually handle errors.  The former case is supported by `Application.ThreadException` (in WinForms) and `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.  The latter case is generally not possible, as there is usually not enough context in a central location to make decisions about how to recover from errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for ASP.NET you can add a `Global.asax` file to the website and handle the `Application_Error` method.

This is how I generally use it:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource",
            "Application");
    }
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MySource",
        Server.GetLastError().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Incase the OP was't aware though, the stuff in that method about EventLog etc isn't required - you can handle it anyway you want.  The important bit is the signature of the method in Global.asax and `Server.GetLastError()` which gives you the most recently thrown exception.

Answer (score 8):

Use `AppDomain`'s `UnhandledException` event:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // log the exception 
    }
```

For ASP.NET use you will use glabal.asax.

Answer (score 0):

You could try AOP based addons like PostSharp that injects your exception handling code to your classes and/or methods that have custom attributes. This is done post-compile, so your source code remains clean. Check this out - http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms, you could have a look at [my other answer related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406385/handling-unhandled-exceptions-problem#406473). It does use `try-catch` though, as there is no other way that I know off.

See other answers for ASP.NET and possible other .NET uses.