# Console Window Closes Despite Using Console.Read()

Tags: c#, console-application

I wrote a C# tool which is running as a standard console application. At the end of the program I used `Console.Read()` to prevent the window to close. This works fine for all my colleagues PC except one. He never saw my application. It did all the work to do but it closes afterwards. All PC run WinXP. Do you have any idea?

I implemented a try-catch-finally where the finally includes nothing but `Console.Read()`.

**EDIT:** I added some code

```
Console.SetWindowSize(125, 40);
CopyToolBase ctb = null;
try
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan duration;

    ctb = CopyToolBase.GetInstance(Defines.configPath);
    if (null == ctb)
    {
        throw new KopiertoolException();
    }

    if (null == ctb.GetNewestVersion())
    {
        throw new KopiertoolException();
    }

    if (!ctb.CheckCopy())
    {
        throw new KopiertoolException();
    }

    if (!ctb.CopyAndUnzip())
    {
        throw new KopiertoolException();
    }

    duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);

    ctb.PrintSuccess("xxxxxxxx");
    ctb.PrintInfo("Gesamtdauer: " + ((duration.Hours == 0) ? "" : string.Format("{0:00} Std ", duration.Hours)) + string.Format("{0:00} Min {1:00} Sek", duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds));

    startTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (!ctb.StartTask())
    {
        throw new KopiertoolException();
    }

    duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);

    if (duration.Minutes > 1)
    {
        ctb.PrintInfo("Dauer: " + ((duration.Hours == 0) ? "" : string.Format("{0:00} Std ", duration.Hours)) + string.Format("{0:00} Min {1:00} Sek", duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds));
    }
}
catch (KopiertoolException)
{
    ctb.WriteToLog();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ctb == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxx");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        ctb.PrintError("xxxxxxxxx");
        ctb.PrintError(ex.ToString());
        ctb.WriteToLog();
    }
}            
finally
{
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: I would try to log the key recieved on last Console.Read(..), to see what key pressed on that PC, if this is possible naturally.

Comment: I provided some code.
@Maarten As I mentioned, I already use a try-catch-finally.

Comment: Have you tried running this application from an open Command prompt window on the machine that it fails on? Might shed some more light on its execution path.

Comment: Is the problem reproduced consistently on the computer where it did not work ? And does it always work ok on all the other computers ?

Comment: Maybe the exception is not caught. Try something from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406385/handling-unhandled-exceptions-problem#406473

Comment: I wrote a batch executing the program and than calling PAUSE. But it closed again. In windows task scheduler I saw that the exit code was 1. I can't believe I don't get any logfile and that the window will close automatically...

Comment: Have you tried placing the console.Read after the finally block?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `DLL` imported method (or external library) at all in any section of your `CopyToolBase` class?

If you are then it could be a corrupted state exception being thrown somewhere in the code, which will not be caught by a normal try/catch block, so there might be an exception, its just that the managed code can't handle it and has no choice but to terminate the process.

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) explaining the situation:

I know its a long shot, but thought I'd just cover all the bases