# Catching Unknown Exceptions With C#

Tags: c#, debugging

I have an application (written in C# / ClickOnce) which, for the most part, works fine; it has no memory leaks and runs reliably and is stable for days at a time.

However, it also utilises MEF (so plugins/extensions can be dynamically added to the core assembly). Again, this 'works' currently, but if an exception/fatal error occurs in an externally linked assembly/plugin, it will crash the entire application.

After some recent testing, I found that the application had crashed after around 14 hours of [successful] operation.

With that in mind, my question is really two-fold:

a) is it possible to catch **any** unhanded exception a plugin (or the main application) may throw, so it can at least output info for debugging assistance?

b) I can't be sure if it was the plugin or the main application which failed. Therefore, I cannot think where to start debugging/tracing the issue. How does one go about finding a bug which only occurs after such a long period of time?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: It will depend how the plugin is integrated in your main app, mostly.

Comment: First advice, use log4net or logging library alike. Secondly, attach a handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`. It will be fired any time an unhandled exception occurs. In the exception you always have a stack trace. It will give you precise details about the location of the error.

Comment: @HansPassant e.ExceptionObject.ToString() is not enough. The details like stack trace are essential. Moreover, the actual problem can be described in inner exceptions.

Comment: If you want to support external plugins it's important you sandbox them so that they can never hurt the normal processing of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments (I guess I should have read those before I started typing up an answer...)

When an application throws an exception that is unhandled, it fires the `UnhandledException` event just before death and you can subscribe to that in order to log any details that will help you figure out what happened.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406473/1467396) SO post for an example on how to use it (includes `ThreadException`).