# Application Level Unhandled Exceptions Not Creating New File

Tags: wpf, exception, c#-4.0, error-handling

I have a bit of code in my App.cs file to catch unhandled exceptions in the event of a crash.  The problems is when I step through the code, it reads as if the file exists, but no new file is actually created.  I am probably overlooking something simple but I could use a second (or more ;)) set of eyes on it.  Here is my method.

```
private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var contents =
        string.Format(
            "HResult:    {1}{0}" + "HelpLink:   {2}{0}" + "Message:    {3}{0}" + "Source:     {4}{0}"
            + "StackTrace: {5}{0}" + "{0}",
            Environment.NewLine,
            e.Exception.HResult,
            e.Exception.HelpLink,
            e.Exception.Message,
            e.Exception.Source,
            e.Exception.StackTrace);

    if (!File.Exists("/Source/CrashLogs/Exceptions.txt"))
    {
        File.WriteAllText("/Source/CrashLogs/Exceptions.txt", contents);
    }
    else
    {
        File.AppendAllText("/Source/CrashLogs/Exceptions.txt", contents);
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I'll next expand this out so that the file name contains the current date, but I would just like to get it running first.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is folder `/Source/CrashLogs/` already exists?

handle also `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`
more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406385/handling-unhandled-exceptions-problem)

Comment: It does, inside the project folder.  I'll take a look at the link you posted as well.  Thanks.